# iPhone:Twitter integration

Tags: iphone, twitter

I followed the below link to integrate Twitter into my application.
http://icodeblog.com/2009/07/09/integrating-twitter-into-your-applications/

It was working great earlier. It was updating my comments to twitter account in web perfectly. But after long time, i am testing the samething now, but it is not working at all, its not updating to twitter. I checked with iOS 3.0 SDK as well as 4.0 to run this project. when i see the logs in my iphone project, it shows as below:

> 

#### Response denied by WatchGuard HTTP proxy.

**Reason:**  all proposed authentication schemes denied 

 **Method:**  POST 
 **Host:**  twitter.com 
 **Path:**  /statuses/update.xml

Does anyone has any idea how do i approach on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use oAuth for twitter now. Previous authentication is no longer supported by twitter. [Check the authentication section](http://dev.twitter.com/doc) for details. And you can use [Twitter-oAuth-iPhone](http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/) to make life easier.

Comment: Sure. Thank you very much. I'll read that. Also is there any sample to integrate using this latest method on iPhone development?

Comment: Check the edit. Twitter-OAuth-iPhone contains a demo project.

Comment: Hi, I tried Twitter-OAuth-iPhone demo project. It asked me to provide Consumer key and Consumer secret. I created and provided it. After that, when i run this project, it asked me username and password, i entered it, after that there is being a blank grey screen shown. Where i can write comments to post to twitter in this sample? (or) Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Check your tweets. Though it shows only a gray screen, it sends a update. [_engine sendUpdate: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Already Updated. %@", [NSDate date]]]; This line in Demo/Src/OAuthTwitterDemoViewController.m. You can edit this message to test your own tweet. And remember, now twitter don't support same message twice.

Comment: Check OAuchTwitterDemoViewController.m closely. The demo code is self explanatory.